# Reading numbers with getChar() in C++

Tags: c++, io, getchar

I'd like to make a function reading integers from `stdin` in the fastest way possible. To be more specific I've got a very long sequence of `int`s separated with spaces finished with `EOF` on which I've got to make some operations. I used `cin` but since this function is quite robust in its possibilites I'd like to make something smaller, more specific, and thus, faster and more efficient. I've read that the fastes way of reading `stdin` is `getChar()` function. I've already found some implementations of this problem in C, but chars there are just another form of integers and in C++ they're not. My idea is to make a function of type `bool`

`bool myIntRead( int *num);`

which would basically read chars of an integer until a 'space sign' and somehow put these chars back into an `int` number. The `bool` type would be used to inform that the `stdin` is empty.

```
int main() {
    int num;
    while (myIntRead(&num) ) {
        myIntRead(&num)
        //some operations on num
    }
}
```

I'm fully aware that this sort of dealing with input is much more complex and more difficult but I'd really like to find out a solution to this problem. I will really appreaciate some help from You Guys in finding out an implementation of this concept.
Best regards!

Comment: `char` is an integral type. You can treat it like a small integer. I think that by "C++ they're not" you are talking about *character literals*, not the result of `getchar()`.

Comment: Incidentally, be prepared for the possibility that getchar() is reading from a terminal which is `line buffered` such that you will typically not receive any input until a newline is entered at the completion of an entire number, and then you will start getting it character by character from the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to deal with ASCII input and you're sure that input will be provided to you in the expected format (ie. digits 0-9 followed b space) then all you have to do is read each character and then:

- Determine if it's a space or a digit
- If it's a space, start reading a new number
- If it's a digit append digit to current number

The following illustrates that. But it doesn't handle any overflow and there is no stop condition..

```
int c;
int current_number;
std::vector<int> numbers;


do {
   c = getchar();

   if(c == 0x20)                      // it's a space
   {
       numbers.push_back(current_number);    // add the current number to the list of numbers
       current_number = 0;                   // reset the current_number variable back to 0
   }else if(c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39)   // it's a digit
   {
       current_number = current_number * 10 + (c - 0x30);   // add next digit..
       // you may want to deal with overflow here (ie. if number of digits > MAX_DIGITS or similar)
   }

} while (TRUE);           // there should be a stop condition here..
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking about similar approach. But I still can't find any solution to how from a single digit make a whole number. In Java I'd concatate it but in C++ there is no such a way. If I use `int n = (int) getChar()` i have a full int. So how should I deal with it?

Comment: Wow, that looks great, from what I see U used hex representation of ASCII but I always have problems with remembering them, so can I use char representation of them? So instead of `c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39` there'd be `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` hm? And please explain to me the `current_number = current_number * 10 + (c - 0x30);` because I don't get why are you multiplying in by ten, and do other operations?

Comment: And I've got one more question to You. Since a sequence of integers would be up to 10^7 I'm afraid that collecting all of them to the vector might be a bad idea, so can we get rid of it? I'd like to just read very fast and show it without any saving in in the stack? To You think that we can do that?

Comment: yes, you can use the char representation. The `current_number = current_number * 10 + (c - 0x30)` is just performing base 10 composition of the number. Just work through an example to see why it works (ie. `537 = (5*10 + 3)*10 + 7`). Finally, it's up to you what you do with the numbers.. I just gave an example of how to read them. If you don't need to store them then, by all means, don't store them.

Comment: The way how the result is produced occured to me a moment ago but now I've got last question: if I dress these things into a nice function returning a whole integer may I writie 
<br>
`while ((n=myIntRead()) != -1) {
 // operations on n
 }`  <br>
(of course before while loop variable 'n' would be declared first) The reason for this would be to call this reading function only once for one number from a sequence. Would it be correct?

Comment: @vladimir1923 - yes, you can certainly wrap that up into a function and just process each number before moving on to the next..

Comment: the algorithm provided by You implemented into an inline function returning read numer, decreased the time of reading a few milions of integers and making quite many operations on them from 0.98 to 0.36 sec. That was what I was looking for. Thank U and take care!

Answer (score 0):

the following code reads 1000000 (one million) numbers in 61ms (normal PC some years old). The file has the size of 3.8MB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template< typename T, typename Out >
struct IntReader_type
{
    IntReader_type( Out out ) : out_( out ) {}
    template< typename E, typename Traits >
    friend std::basic_istream< E, Traits >& operator>>( std::basic_istream< E, Traits >& in, IntReader_type rdr )
    {
        std::basic_istream< E, Traits >::sentry ok( in );
        if( ok )
        {
            std::ios_base::iostate state = std::ios_base::goodbit;
            try
            {
                const std::ctype< E >& ct = std::use_facet< std::ctype< E > >( in.getloc() );
                while( state == std::ios_base::goodbit )
                {
                    T result = T(0);
                    for( Traits::int_type m = in.rdbuf()->sgetc(); ; m = in.rdbuf()->snextc() )
                    {
                        if( Traits::eq_int_type( m,  Traits::eof() ) )
                        {
                            state |= std::ios_base::eofbit; // EOF is not an error
                            break;
                        }
                        const E c = Traits::to_char_type( m );
                        if( ct.is( std::ctype_base::space, c ) )
                            break;
                        if( ct.is( std::ctype_base::digit, c ) )
                        {
                            (result *= 10) += T(c - E('0'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            state |= std::ios_base::failbit; // not a digit
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    *(rdr.out_)++ = result; // store the number
                    // skip white space character
                    for( Traits::int_type m = in.rdbuf()->sgetc(); ; m = in.rdbuf()->snextc() )
                    {
                        if( Traits::eq_int_type( m,  Traits::eof() ) )
                        {
                            state |= std::ios_base::eofbit;
                            break;
                        }
                        if( !ct.is( std::ctype_base::space, Traits::to_char_type( m ) ) )
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                state |= std::ios_base::badbit;
                if( in.exceptions() & std::ios_base::badbit )
                    throw;
            }
            in.setstate( state );
        }
        return in;
    }
private:
    Out out_;
};
template< typename T, typename Out >
IntReader_type< T, Out > read_ints( Out out )
{
    return IntReader_type< T, Out >( out );
}
```

call the Integer-reader in this way:

```
vector< int > numbers;
if( cin >> read_ints< int >( back_inserter(numbers) ) ) 
{   // read is done without error
```

be careful - in this version only unsigned numbers can be read and there is no check of integer overflow.

Comment: If You don't want to save the numbers, but only show them, then simple change the iterator to a `std::ostream_iterator< int >( cout, " " )`
In this case the program runs much slower, because of the output!

Comment: Thank You very muh for such an elaborate answer! This code is a great source of knowledge for me and studying it will elucidate me on areas I havn't known yet. :) Now, however, I will try to implement @MikyDinescu 's answer which seems simplistic enough for me to use it with full awareness. Either way - thank U very much!

Answer (score -1):

ok, so `c = getchar();`

You have to store in in an array for it to be processable.

If `c`  contains one digit, multiply c[0] * 1.

If `c`  contains two digits, multiply c[1] * 1 + c[0] * 10.

If `c`  contains three digits, multiply c[2] * 1 + c[1] * 10 + c[0] * 100.

If `c`  contains four digits, multiply c[3] * 1 + c[2] * 10 + c[1] * 100 + c[0] * 1000, etc etc.

The code for input looks like this:

```
   while(digitInput!=13)
   {
       if (kbhit())
       {
           digitInput=getch();
           if (digitInput==27) exit(0);

           if ((digitInput>47) && (digitInput<59))
           {
             digitArray[digit]=(unsigned char)digitInput-48;
             digit++;

             printf("%d",digitInput-48);

           }
           if (digitInput==13)  { digitn=digitArray[0]; break; }
       }
   }



switch(digit)
   {
       case 0:
       case 1:
            digitn=digitArray[0]*1 ;
       break;

       case 2:
            digitn= digitArray[1]*1  +digitArray[0]*10  ;
       break;

       case 3:
            digitn=  digitArray[2]*1+digitArray[1]*10 +digitArray[0]*100  ;
       break;

       case 4:
             digitn=digitArray[3]*1+digitArray[2]*10+digitArray[1]*100+digitArray[0]*1000 ;
       break;
}
```

The complete app in code.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int digit=0,digitInput=0;
int digitArray[10]={0},digitn;
int numberOfInputDigits=4;

/*********************************
 *                               *
 ********************************/

void getIntKey(void)
{
   digitArray[0]=0;
   digitArray[1]=0;
   digit=0;
   digitInput=0;

   while(digitInput!=13)
   {
       if (kbhit())
       {
           digitInput=getch();
           if (digitInput==27) exit(0);

           if ((digitInput>47) && (digitInput<59))
           {
             digitArray[digit]=(unsigned char)digitInput-48;
             digit++;

             printf("%d",digitInput-48);

           }
           if (digitInput==13)  { digitn=digitArray[0]; break; }
       }
   }

   switch(digit)
   {
       case 0:
       case 1:
            digitn=digitArray[0]*1 ;
       break;

       case 2:
            digitn= digitArray[1]*1  +digitArray[0]*10  ;
       break;

       case 3:
            digitn=  digitArray[2]*1+digitArray[1]*10 +digitArray[0]*100  ;
       break;

       case 4:
             digitn=digitArray[3]*1+digitArray[2]*10+digitArray[1]*100+digitArray[0]*1000 ;
       break;

       case 5:
             digitn=digitArray[4]*1+digitArray[3]*10+digitArray[2]*100+digitArray[1]*1000+digitArray[0]*10000 ;
       break;

       case 6:
             digitn=digitArray[5]*1+digitArray[4]*10+digitArray[3]*100+digitArray[2]*1000+digitArray[1]*10000 
                   +digitArray[0]*100000;
       break;


       case 7:
             digitn=digitArray[6]*1+digitArray[5]*10+digitArray[4]*100+digitArray[3]*1000+digitArray[2]*10000 
                   +digitArray[1]*100000 +digitArray[0]*1000000;
       break;


       case 8:
             digitn=digitArray[7]*1+digitArray[6]*10+digitArray[5]*100+digitArray[4]*1000+digitArray[3]*10000 
                   +digitArray[2]*100000 +digitArray[1]*1000000+digitArray[0]*10000000;
       break;

       case 9:
             digitn=digitArray[8]*1+digitArray[7]*10+digitArray[6]*100+digitArray[5]*1000+digitArray[4]*10000 
                   +digitArray[3]*100000 +digitArray[2]*1000000+digitArray[1]*10000000 +digitArray[0]*100000000;
       break;


   }


  // if (digitInput!=13)  digitn=digitArray[3]*1+digitArray[2]*10+digitArray[1]*100+digitArray[0]*1000 ;
   printf("\n%i\n\n",digitn);
}

/*********************************
 *                               *
 ********************************/

int main()
{
    system("color 1F");     //Blue background       
   printf("Digits Into decimal numbers \n ");
   printf("Max Input is %d Digits   \n ",numberOfInputDigits);
   printf("\nInput Digit >");
   getIntKey();

   printf("\nThe input was   digitArray[7]=%d \n",digitArray[7]);

   printf("digitArray[6]=%d \n",digitArray[6]);
   printf("digitArray[5]=%d \n",digitArray[5]);
   printf("digitArray[4]=%d \n",digitArray[4]);

   printf("digitArray[3]=%d \n",digitArray[3]);
   printf("digitArray[2]=%d \n",digitArray[2]);
   printf("digitArray[1]=%d \n",digitArray[1]);
   printf("digitArray[0]=%d \n",digitArray[0]);
   printf("\n%i\n\n",digitn);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I wasn't the one to downvote this, it does seem rather roundabout.  Why do you believe it is necessary to store the inputs in an array, and not simply multiply the accumulated value by 10 each time another valid digit is input?

Comment: Thank u very much but like @ChrisStratton I think it's redundant to store all these values and "manually" choose multiplication way. Either way thanks!